# Cannot load a bitmap to image view

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am just learning how to develop android apps but i came across an error in which i cannot load a decoded bitmap to my image view
My image view is declared in linear layout (vertical) as

```
<ImageView>
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:width="match_parent"
/>
```

And i am adding bitmap by this process in onCreate() method

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
iv.setImageBitmap(bv);
```

When i run this code it shows me a dialog box showin your project contains errors ...
Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors your project contains?? Specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to rightly define you `ImageView`, it should be, without right bracket `>`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:width="match_parent"
/>
```

Secondly, if you want to set image from resources, you can simply use `setImageResource()`:

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try loading the drawable instead of the bitmap.

```
iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) for more details